# New Instance of class from List Box value

Tags: java

I want to use a class that is called by the string displayed in a list box.

Like I would have

"Class1"
"Class2"

in the list box, and use it like:

new "Class1"

Is this possible?

Comment: What is a "list box"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible using reflection.  First, find the class.

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("Class1");  // or a variable containing the class name
```

Be careful, [`forName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) requires a fully-qualified class name (e.g. `java.lang.String`).

Then call [`newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) on the class object.

```
Object instance = clazz.newInstance();
```

Each of those method calls throws multiple exceptions that you'll need to catch.

Answer (score 2):

If all the possible classes are known beforehand by you, you could use a [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to build instances based on the strings received.